# jquery tab cookies limit

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

is there limit to how much tabs cookie can remember? I have a series of 6 main tabs, and subtabs in page. Number of subtabs varies depends on main tab. I noticed that cookie remember tabs if i have 15 or less subtab but if i have more then that number, cookie value is 0 after reloading browser. Is there some limit in configuration?

I create main tab with:

```
var $mainTab = $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      cookie: {
            name: 'mainCookie',
            expires: 1
        }
    });
```

And subtabs like this:

```
 var $tab1 = $( "#tabs-1" ).tabs({
          cookie: {
            name: 's',
            expires: 1
        }
    });
```

Then on page load read value:

```
var c_main = $.cookie('mainCookie');
var c_sub = $.cookie('s');
```

Main tab is always ok, but as i said, subtab works only if that main tab have less then or 15 tabs.

Comment: Cookie can store max 4k of data. CHeck if your data goes beyond that.

Comment: i dont think i reached that,as only thing i store is number of selected tab (for example 13 or so). Its not some long string or something. Only if jquery ui tab cookie solution adds a lot more to cookie. Anyway, chrome development tool shows 3 and 11 in size values for my two cookies.that are probably bytes? Is there some easier way to check if limit is reached? javascript doesnt return any error.

Comment: here is the sample, so you can see what i did, http://jsfiddle.net/DsJRx/2/

Comment: maybe something is wrong in my code, i cant believe that cookie hit 4k   with this kind of information i store.